# I get the following error on the "Confirm Hosts" step in Ambari (creating cluster):

Tags: azure, hadoop, ambari

[image]

The Registration log contains the following error:

```
==========================
Running setup agent script...
==========================
Command start time 2017-11-26 12:05:31
```

('  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_agent/main.py", line 355, in main
    (retries, connected, stopped) = netutil.try_to_connect(server_url, MAX_RETRIES, logger)
UnboundLocalError: local variable \'server_url\' referenced before assignment
INFO 2017-11-26 12:00:19,304 ExitHelper.py:53 - Performing cleanup before exiting...

I tried it a few times from scratch and I get the same result. ANy ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What version of Ambari?

Comment: I was using a free trial subscription... So I tried it on my regular Azure subscription and I got a bit further... But I now get the following error:

"Ambari agent machine hostname (lon-hadoop) does not match expected ambari server hostname (lon-hadoop-55.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com). Aborting registration. Please check hostname, hostname -f and /etc/hosts file to confirm your hostname is setup correctly."

Comment: @cricket_007 -> What version? Well, I downloaded it on CentOS-based 7.3 today from the ambari repo using the following command - 
wget -nv http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos7/2.x/updates/2.4.2.0/ambari.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/ambari.repo

Comment: Ambari 2.4.2 is old. Also, do you need HDP in Azure? If so, you should probably be using Cloudbreak. https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Cloudbreak/Cloudbreak-2.1.0/content/azure-create/index.html